# A self-motivational technique - authorization of results - looking for origins

Tags: learning, motivation, concentration, children

I have recently read an article that describes a technique called "authorization of results". The technique suggests a particular protocol of self-reviewing any achieved result of a completed task:

0. define a desired outcome - prior to the task, then after completion go over the next steps, preferably in writing
1. describe the situation prior to the task completion
2. describe your actions performed to complete it in "I"-statements in active voice
3. describe the achieved result and confirm that it matches the desired outcome
4. describe how the achieved result will benefit you

The purpose of the technique is to create a positive emotional response of a completion and satisfaction that will serve as a reward and so improve future motivation.

The original source is in Russian and it does not cite any origins of this technique. Author mentions that she learned this protocol from some teaching materials on children with difficulties in learning and concentration, and that she is not able to track these materials anymore. Here's a link to the source (Russian): https://vk.com/@ntukkel-99-avtorizaciya-rezultata-anna-obuhova?ref=group_block

I have tried to search for these in both Russian and English unsuccessfully, so I suspect that author might remember the name of the technique somewhat incorrectly, or origins may be it yet another language, etc.

I am interested in any hints as to what it may sound like and where this technique could actually stem from.